# update sql database from entity model

Tags: sql, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

is there any way to update my sql 2008 db from model?
i maped model from db, and added some changes like associations and change fields name in some tables, can i update now db using my model?

Answer (score 1):

Over by the solution explorer there is a model tree view. In there right click the model and there should be generate database from model.

Comment: yee there is update model from DB, but i want to update DB from model, so oposite.

Comment: Theres two options at the top, one updates the db the other updates the model.

Comment: no mate, one is update model from DB, second generate db acording to the model.

Comment: if you are changing the model and want to update the database, use generate database from model.

Comment: No where in your question does it say anything about data existing in the database. If your question was complete, I could answer it better.